# Where am I failing in writing this mocha-zombie node.js test?

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, zombie.js

I'm trying to setup a new node.js project (something with express and stuff). But before I get anything, I want to setup testing. Since I'm completely new to TDD with node.js, I'm having trouble setting this up.

Can some kind soul tell me why is this little test passing? It doesn't matter if I put the correct URL, whatever. It just passes.

```
var assert=require('assert');
var Browser = require("zombie");
var browser = new Browser();
describe('Home page', function () {
   describe ('title', function () {
        it ('should have a title', function () {
            browser.visit ("http://no-such-site.com/").
            then(function (){
                assert.equal(browser.text("title"), "Whatever goes here");
            }).
            fail(function(err) {
                console.log("Failed with error: ", error);
            });
        });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `done` parameter to your `it` function.

```
var assert=require('assert');
var Browser = require("zombie");
var browser = new Browser();
describe('Home page', function () {
  describe ('title', function () {
    it ('should have a title', function (done) {
        browser.visit ("http://no-such-site.com/").
        then(function (){
            assert.equal(browser.text("title"), "Whatever goes here");
            done(); 
        }).
        fail(function(err) {
            console.log("Failed with error: ", error);
            done(err);
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Still passes test. I even added kljvfrhw() call in the test, it still works.

Comment: Well, it does not, I forgot to add (done) to it functions' second argument argument :)